# Finding zone by depth of the gray scale image

Tags: image, algorithm, image-processing

As title mentioned, I want to depict the contour of a gray scale image without edge detection.
After scanning the image, we can find a series of zone, each zone is consist of near depth pixels.Is there any efficient algorithm can reduce processing time?

I think an algorithm may work.Scanning all pixel in the image, merge the neighbor whose depth is near each scanned pixel and recursively expand this region.
But I don't know how to limit the range, when should I stop the expanding process?
I hope this limit can change to adapt each different input image.
Should I load the image first to get its histogram of depth, and maybe by a math calculation to get this range? but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not *without* edge detection. It will be the edge that will stop your areas from growing. Simply you are detecting the edges differently. But the idea seems very bright to me.

You'll have though the problems with accidental jumps in brightness (you call it depth).

I would use something alike the bucket algorithm, used by graphic editors. Grow the area not by pixel, but by whole area, which brightness is close to the starting one. As for the closeness demanded, I think, it should be set very dynamically, according to the standard deviations in the parts of area already found and close to the question place.